# RCP TT cannot record for my application

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp, eclipse-rcptt

I am trying to use the record feature in RCP TT but it keeps failing to start with this error:

> org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.rcptt.tesla.internal.ui.SWTUIPlayer

The application i am running is a RCP app and RCPTT can run it fine but when i try to use the record it fails.

I have located the class it is looking for in the org.eclipse.rcptt.tesla.swt plugin so i am unsure why it cant find it is there some sort of run config i must change?

I was thinking this may be a bug in the RCPTT but it can record one of my other apps no problem so that makes me think its something to do with the way my app runs?

Comment: How do you build your product ? make sure `org.eclipse.rcptt.tesla.swt` is in the deployed product

Comment: Worked a treat thanks ;)

Comment: You can add that to an answer if you like and ill accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `org.eclipse.rcptt.tesla.swt` is in the deployed product